# Auto-delete .exe file from Pyinstaller

Tags: python

I want auto-delete the .exe file generated by Pyinstaller, during my update.

```
self_file_name = os.path.abspath(sys.executable)
os.remove(self_file_name)
```

But I got the error access denied.

How can I do that?

Comment: You want the executable to delete itself?

Comment: Yes, the script copy the new version of .exe and start it. So, I want self delete the old version.

Comment: Then why do you need to delete it?   Just have the binary quit, have the script take over and update the exe and then run the exe.

Comment: My script detect if a new version is available on the network disk remote, if its true, It copy the new version in the same directory as the old version. Next I start the new version, so I want delete the old one

Comment: I don't think Windows will allow you to delete the executable you are running or that is still running.

Comment: Yes its my question Klaus D, I would know if it's possible to do this